# Reducing data to one dimension using PCA

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pca

Can the dimension of the data be reduced to only one principal component?

I tried it on the iris data set-

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pca = PCA(n_components=1)
pca_X = pca.fit_transform(X)   #X = standardized iris data

pca_df = pd.DataFrame(pca_X, columns=["PCA1"])

plt.plot(pca_df["PCA1"], "o")
```

[image]

We can see three different clusters. So can to dimension be reduced to 1?

Comment: Check [this article](http://bebi103.caltech.edu.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/2015/tutorials/r5_pca.html)

Comment: pca_df is already one dimension

Comment: Please post a **full** [mre] (including the import and normalization of the data), which should be straightforward since you use the iris dataset; plus, it is not clear why you think the number of clusters has anything to do with the number of dimensions/components.

Comment: this is data science question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose to reduce the dimensions to 1 using PCA, the only thing it promises is that the resultant principal component is in the direction of highest variance in the data.

If you are reducing the dimensions in order to improve classification you can use Linear Discriminant Analysis which gives you the direction of maximum separation between the classes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the dimension can be reduced to 1, which is exactly what you have done in your example.

The y Axis in your plot shows the coordinate for each observation wrt the first principal component.

The *three* clusters likely relate to the three species in the Iris dataset and have nothing to do with the number of components.